# Why is the strong acid written in a net ionic equation?

Tags: acid-base, aqueous-solution, solutions, solubility

Strong acids dissolve and break apart into ions, so in a net ionic equation, why are they written?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the strong acid starts not in the aqueous phase, then you can't cancel out the ions that it dissociates into. Also, these ions may participate in a reaction, for example, neutralization with a base or precipitation via its conjugate base. In such cases involving double displacement reactions, the component ions cannot be both cancelled out.

Example 1:
$$\ce{HCl_{(aq)} + NaOH_{(aq)} -> H2O_{(l)} + NaCl_{(aq)}}$$
Only $\ce{Na+}$ and $\ce{Cl-}$ are spectator ions that could be cancelled out.

Example 2:
$$\ce{HCl_{(aq)} + AgNO3_{(aq)} -> AgCl_{(s)} + HNO3_{(aq)}}$$
Only $\ce{H+}$ and $\ce{NO3-}$ are spectator ions that could be cancelled out.

Comment: So is it just an exception to the rule?

Comment: What's this rule you speak of?

Comment: The rule is that all aqueous ions are cancelled out on both sides on a net ionic equation

Comment: But they have to be aqueous on _both_ sides of the equation. These are not.

Comment: So when a acid combines with a base, they produce a solid?

Comment: In water, acid base neutralizations produce water, which is a liquid.